# Rails 4 gem creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to write my first rails 4 gem. There are lib folder that include general 'import_1c.rb' gem file in which I wrote:

```
module Import1c
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

It's also fine. File is processing successfully. But there is also lib/app folder which contains controllers, models, views and lib/config which contains route file. In gemspec I write next:

```
spec.files         = Dir['lib/**/**/*']
```

And also if I write: `puts spec.files` - I will see all my gems files. But no one file, except import_1c, is not processing while I'm not include it into general gem file.

Comment: why dont you use spec.files = `git ls-files`.split($/) (back ticks are misinterpreted)

Comment: I try it but it's not helpful for my problem.

Comment: I think it s not a problem of gemspec, by convention, if you create an engine, put your app folder at the root of it, not in lib

Comment: I'm try it, too. I'm not check about controllers/models. But routes file was not processing(verify by byebug).

Comment: weird, are they in `/config/routes.rb` ?

Comment: Yes. But no matter, now:)
I'm fool:) I create gem instead plugin. I'm hope it was the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I create gem instead plugin. Like:

```
 rails plugin new import_1c --mountable
```